# JavaScript Arithmetic Operators...where are they?

Tags: javascript

What is the precise nature of JS's arithmetic operators (+, -, *, /)? I imagine they're functions, but they're not on Number's or String's prototype, and they're definitely not first class citizens. Are they just their own thing?

Comment: Did you read the ECMAScript specification? What exact part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ - All the standard operators have their own sections (eg. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus) that cover the [sometimes complex] rules of their behavior. These standard operators are generally not associated with any "object"; think of C.

Comment: `Did you read the ECMAScript specification?`  @RolandIllig  Please remind me never to invite you to any of my parties.. :)  Anyway, I'm of to read the Oxford dictionary.

Comment: @Keith You're right, I overdid it. The Mozilla documentation would have been much more friendly in this case. My general point was that when someone asks a question, they should tell what they already tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're known as [**infix operators**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation), and they're inbuilt, and act like [**Function prototypes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype).

It's interesting to note that regular JavaScript doesn't support things like exponentiation through infix operators, and you're forced to resort to an extension of `Math`:

```js
console.log(Math.pow(7, 2));
```

Although ES6 fixes this:

```js
console.log(7 ** 2);
```

Although you can't create your own infix operators, you can extend them:

```js
Function.prototype['∘'] = function(f){
  return x => this(f(x))
}

const multiply = a => b => (a * b)
const double = multiply (2)
const doublethreetimes = (double) ['∘'] (double) ['∘'] (double)

console.log(doublethreetimes(3));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That's not creating an operator. That's just extending `Function.prototype`.

Comment: The standard operators are definitely *not* function prototypes. Being able to create 'similar like things' is a different conversation.

Comment: Thanks. Some people really didn't like my question, but I'm glad I asked it.