# Are there built-in arithmetic functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Very simple (stupid?) question: are there built-in arithmetic functions in JS such as addition or multiplication?

For example some imaginary `Math.add` which can be used like this:

```
[ 3, 1, 2 ].reduce( Math.add ) // 6
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: unfortunately, there's no such thing.

Comment: Most arithmetic functions can be expressed in only a few characters. So if you want you, can put all of these in an utility library if you so desire. `(a,b)=>a+b`, `(a,b)=>a*b` etc

Comment: @Shilly, yeah, i know. Just asking in case i'm not aware of some JS features. We can use functions like Number or Boolean to filter or map arrays, so i got curious if we can use some other built-in functions in order to commit some other operations using no custom functions at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872200/javascript-arithmetic-operators-where-are-they

Comment: You could write one yourself: `const addNumbers = (...arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b)` And call with `addNumbers(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi lucifer63 the function you are asking for like add, sum might not be available but that you can do by the operator but for the little complex operation we do have

- For Example 
  `Math.round(4.7);` 
  `Math.PI;`
  `Math.pow(8, 2);`
  `Math.sqrt(64);`

if you check out the [w3school Link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_math.asp) you can find more math function's which are also very usefull

Comment: Great. Now can we combine some of these methods to get some kind of addition function?

Comment: @lucifer63 the answer provided by benjaminjosephw `const add = (x, y) => x + y; [ 3, 1, 2 ].reduce( add );` can be your solution because using different Math library function to create an add (sum) might not be suitable (or even possible)

Answer (score 1):

No but you could very easily define this yourself:

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y;
[ 3, 1, 2 ].reduce( add );
```